# resistor at external clock source line

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, serial, clock, source

im reading a arm based mcu board schematic and there is 100R resistor (R30) at external 25MHz oscillator source. What is the main reason of using serial resistor at clock line ?

[image: schematic]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/7737/80284, this resistor will be important if traces are long, or there's significant mismatch in impedance between the endpoints.

Comment: Or just for EMI reduction by reducing slope steepness. The schmitt trigger input of the CPU will still produce a clean squarewave as clock.

Comment: Reducing reflections caused by a low-impedance source driving a square wave into a high-impedance load.

Comment: So how can i determine the right value for my design? 100R is typically for it ?