# What does measuring voltage do to the current or signal of a pin?

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, signal, voltmeter

I have a problematic digital signal which starts working when I measure the voltage between the pin and ground. What's the effect of a voltmeter on a pin (or to rest of the circuit) when you measure voltage?

Does it mimic:
- a small or large resistor in series or parallel?
- a pull-down resistor?
- a capacitor?
- a better ground connection for the pin?
- more wires between the pin and target?
- a ferrite bead?
- other suggestion?

I'm looking for a way to implement the obvious effect the voltmeter has on the signal functionality but on the circuit proper.

Can one even state what effect measuring voltage has on that which is measured, or can it behave like any/all of the above suggestions?

**EDIT - SOLVED, see answer below**

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't grounding a floating input pin with your multimeter? Most digital inputs these days are CMOS type and you can't leave them floating without expecting trouble of the type you are describing.

Comment: Why don't you describe the signal and what is wrong with it? Replicating a multimeter input may not be the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Justme You're right, but I haven't been able to get help for my specific device, so I thought I'd try a more general approach. Here's my post about my specific issues: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452797/digital-signal-appears-to-improve-with-length-of-wire-troubleshooting-multiple?noredirect=1#comment1138939_452797

Comment: @Transistor Yeah the pin is not floating, it's outputting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I attempted to replicate what the voltmeter was doing to the signal based upon the help received here. I tried connecting the signal pin with ground via 1M resistor, then 10M ohm, then 10M ohm plus a capacitor (which should've been approximating the voltmeter's effect), but none worked.

Removing the resistors and placing the 100nF capacitor as close as possible between the two signals did the trick. Strangely, however, holding the cap with my fingers and pressing it on the connections worked, but after soldering it on it didn't. Tried it three times to no avail. The difference in connection location was just millimeters, so it was very strange. However one difference between the manual testing and soldering the cap onto the board was the length of wires on the cap. Leaving it full length and soldering it on works. So seems like those extra couple of cm of wire and a well-placed cap was what was missing!

Although I've understood that in general one shouldn't be placing caps on signal lines, so that's why I didn't try this earlier. Weird that it works, but I'm very glad!

[image: wonky placement of cap, but it works]

Answer (score 2):

A voltmeter acts like a high-value resistor and a small-value capacitor between the two points where the probes are attached. If one of the probes is on ground, then you could consider this a pull-down resistor. The resistor will be in the 1M\$\Omega\$ range for an inexpensive meter, much higher for a good lab-quality instrument. If the point where you place the probe is **floating** then the resistance can be significant. It usually doesn't matter for logic circuits.

The capacitance may have an effect on high speed logic signals. I don't know, but I would guess that the capacitance might be on the order of 100pF or so.

A third effect, that wasn't on your list, is pressure. When you press the probes onto a circuit node you may improve a poor connection. This is common when there is a poor solder joint, and the pressure of the probe forces the connection to be made.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I had a hunch that the pin might be feeling some slight pull-up effects from two pull-up pins it's sandwiched between, so that the voltmeter acts as a pull-down makes sense to me. Gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your DMM will only update its displayed measurement something like three times a second. Depends on the model but you couldn't read it if it was updated faster than, say, ten times a second and measured large changes anyway, would be flickering unreadably.

So if its a signal slow enough to be seen and measured on a voltmeter then it's only the DMM's input resistance you need to concern yourself with.

That will be stated in the DMM manual's Specifications section. You should be able to find that for your model on the interweb.

It's typically in the order of 10 MOhm.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a reputed multimeter manual. For example, fluke. The input impedance varies sometimes depending on the range of the voltage we are measuring. The voltage scale I mean. If you are planning to do simulations, then I think it should be good enough. There are several Multimeters with varying input impedances depending upon the signal type you are measuring and also the features present in the multimeter. All the good suppliers provide sufficient information in their manuals. Below one from a fluke manual
[image]

> Input impedance for AC V is 1M  Ω  in parallel with 100 pF (not
>   including test leads). Input resistance for DC V is 10M  Ω, unless
>   changed to 10G  Ω  ! for 100 mV, 1 V, & 10 V DC ranges

The above quote is from an agilent multimeter.

Lastly, from a keysight multimeter below
[image]